# Converting C# to VB with Telerik's online convertor

Tags: c#, vb.net, telerik, code-conversion

I have a whole pile of C# classes that I need to convert to VB but I don't understand what some of the C is about.

Here's a typical C# class-

```
using System;

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped = false)]
public partial class CreateServiceToken_1_RequestMessage
{
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.reuters.com/ns/2008/03/01/webservices/rkd/Cache_1")]
    public ThomsonReutersKnowledgeDirect.CacheRequest CacheRequest;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/TokenManagement_1", Order = 0)]
    public ThomsonReutersKnowledgeDirect.CreateServiceToken_Request_1 CreateServiceToken_Request_1;

    public CreateServiceToken_1_RequestMessage()
    {
    }

    public CreateServiceToken_1_RequestMessage(ThomsonReutersKnowledgeDirect.CacheRequest CacheRequest, ThomsonReutersKnowledgeDirect.CreateServiceToken_Request_1 CreateServiceToken_Request_1)
    {
        this.CacheRequest = CacheRequest;
        this.CreateServiceToken_Request_1 = CreateServiceToken_Request_1;
    }
}
```

Telerik's online convertor gives me this in VB:

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()> _
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")> _
<System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped:=False)> _
Partial Public Class CreateServiceToken_1_RequestMessage

    <System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2008/03/01/webservices/rkd/Cache_1")> _
    Public CacheRequest As ThomsonReutersKnowledgeDirect.CacheRequest

    <System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/TokenManagement_1", Order:=0)> _
    Public CreateServiceToken_Request_1 As ThomsonReutersKnowledgeDirect.CreateServiceToken_Request_1

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(CacheRequest As ThomsonReutersKnowledgeDirect.CacheRequest, CreateServiceToken_Request_1 As ThomsonReutersKnowledgeDirect.CreateServiceToken_Request_1)
        Me.CacheRequest = CacheRequest
        Me.CreateServiceToken_Request_1 = CreateServiceToken_Request_1
    End Sub
End Class
```

Problem is that this produces all sorts of errors such as 'System.ServiceModel' is not defined.
Is the <> enclosed stuff required for VB or just left overs from C#?

BTW I'm using VS 2010

Comment: That looks more like C# than C++. Are you sure it's the latter?

Comment: Oops yes c#   It occurred to me to add a project ref to 'System.ServiceModel' and the errors went away.  Still don't understand what it all means but I'll play a bit more and return.  cheers

Comment: @Malcom - Perhaps edit your question now that you've spotted the "VC" "c#" error?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the System.ServiceModel assembly? (This assembly contains the System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute class).

Comment: Why convert them to VB?  Why can't you just compile them as C# assemblies and then reference the assembly from VB?  Depending on your version of VS, a solution can have both VB and C# projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'stuff in <>' is needed, they are [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/z0w1kczw(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Without knowing more, I would say that your errors are due to missing imports\usings.

Look at the top of the C# file, there are many `using something.something` statements.  These should have corresponding `Imports something.something` in the VB file.